# Sveltekit with Fiber: make the Fiber backend render a HTML template if the sveltekit's js crashes

Tags: server-side-rendering, sveltekit, templating, fallback, go-fiber

I'm using the static adapter, mapping / to my Vite build artifacts folder. If the SvelteKit scripts crash, they will return the contents of the `<noscript>` section of it's app.html entrypoint, but as `text/plain`, as opposed to the standard `text/html` one would get when disabling JS intentionally. Is it possible to somehow configure the Fiber backend to detect such crashes and render an appropriate template independently from SvelteKit when this happens?

I expected that the response from sveltekit would even in case of a crash, be sent as text/html and even better, it would render a 500.html page instead of the irrelevant noscript section.